# how can i restore loosing system applications

Tags: applications

I remove some system androids apps(that i dont konw which app) from my phon whith system app safe remover. and now my phon cant open any docx file whith any program. how can do i found the lossing app?
my phon: samsung galexy not N7000 rooted
android: 4.1.2
rom: n7000JPLSB   (rooted)

Comment: How is that you don't know which app you removed? Were you asleep  when you did that?

Comment: First lesson learned, meli: don't use root to touch system stuff unless you exactly know what you're doing. Second lesson along: before *removing* an app, always *freeze* (disable) it to see if everything still works. And lesson 3: if you finally remove something, make sure you 1) have a backup of that, 2) have a complete system backup (Nandroid) is to be recommended, 3) ***remember what you did***. Then, the answer is: restore from your backup. As we can't be sure what else you possibly broke, safest thing is flashing the ROM again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably removed some bloatware which opened word (docx) files. To fix download a docx reader like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=couchDev.tools.DocxParser&hl=en